# Importing .Max Files in Java

Tags: java, 3dsmax

I am a BSCS student doing my final project. I am modelling clothes in 3D Max and want to import my models in JAVA . Remember the extension of 3D Max files is `.Max`. I don't know how to import it.

Comment: Please if anyone can help. If someone wants to add some addition information, hez most welcome

Comment: You mean Java or a specific IDE?

Comment: This is like telling 'my address is "earth"'. You need to mention which 3D engine you are using. Java is a language.

Comment: i want to import them in Net Beans because there i am making my final application. and i am a new user i have modeled cloths in 3D Max as per advise of my supervisor. I am a new user of 3D Max and i dont know about all that "engine" thing. Please tell me which engine to use and what are they meant for. Please guide me as i am a new user . I will be really thankful because right now not knowing about anything is like "being in space" and trying to deliver something on earth.

Comment: I would suggest asking those as separate questions/posts. You will really need to decide on which 3D engine to use first. A 3D engine is a piece of software component that knows how to handle your 3D objects and render them and shows you a scriptable interface to play with.

Comment: kartikg3 which 3D engine do u recommend me. please help , thanks

Answer (score 1):

3dsmax's binary format is closed and cannot open in any other application other then 3dsmax.

What you need is a exporter that exports the mesh data into the format you need for your java application\engine from 3dsmax.
And without any more information it's just a guess for us what format you can use.

Comment: Stig Atle Steffensen please can u brief ur answer me ur or please give me some email , i need some more help..Thanks